# Tab Bar Item change into images

Tags: ios, image, uitabbar

I have this tab bar ViewController and when I want to change the bar button item into an image it doesn't appear.

Can you help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should choose a right-sized image for the Tabbar-item.
The sizes are given here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1

Comment: thanks my friend i downloded some fixed size icons and it worked.thank you

Comment: Your Welcome, Mustafa.